# What are the third parties that receive my online search results?

Tags: legal

In Settings/Details/Legal Notice, there is an explanation of how search results are (or are not) shared with specific third parties. There is a link to a page that lists those third parties:

https://www.ubuntu.com/privacy-policy/third-parties

However the link is broken. Is there a valid link somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The link has been moved a bit. For starters, check https://www.ubuntu.com/privacy-policy/:

> #### Searching in the dash
>
> When you enter a search term into the dash Ubuntu will search your
>   Ubuntu computer and will record the search terms locally. Depending on
>   whether you have opted in or out (see the “Online Search” section
>   below), we may also send your keystrokes as a search term to
>   productsearch.ubuntu.com and selected third parties so that we may
>   complement your search results with online search results from such
>   third parties including: Facebook, Twitter, BBC and Amazon. Canonical
>   and these selected third parties will collect your search terms and
>   use them to provide you with search results while using Ubuntu.
>
> #### By searching in the dash you consent to:
>
> the collection and use of your search terms and IP address in this
>   way; and the storage of your search terms and IP address by Canonical
>   and such selected third parties (if applicable).
>
> ...
>
> [For a current list of our selected third parties, please see the
>   third party privacy policies.](https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy/third-parties)

That last sentence is a link to the updated list. The software just hasn't been updated in accordance (which would probably require a complicated SRU).

---

For completeness, the link lists, at the moment:

```
3sat Mediathek          Foursquare              Sonsgterr
7Digital                GitHub                  SoundCloud
ABC iView               Google docs (Google)    Stack Exchange
Amazon                  Google News             TED Talks
Ask Ubuntu              Headweb                 TMDb
BBC iPlayer             IMDb                    Twitter
Bing Video              is.gd                   Vimeo
Clear Sky Chart         JSTOR                   VODO
COLOURlovers            Launchpad               Weather Underground
Dailymotion             Open Clip Art Library   Wikipedia
deviantArt              Picasa (Google)         Wordnik
Dribbble                PubMed                  Yahoo! Finance
eBay                    Recipe Puppy            Yelp
Encuentro               reddit                  YouTube Education
Etsy                    RTVE                    YouTube Movies
Europeana               SCI-FI-LONDON           YouTube Shows
Facebook                ScienceDirect
Flickr                  Songkick
```